# How many bytes are copied when I use the strcpy function on a String of n characters?

Tags: c, strcpy

for example,

```
char pass[0x10];
char str1[0x10] = "hello";
strcpy(string1, str1)
```

Does this copy 1 * 5 bytes, plus 1 more bytes of the \0 null terminator?
So 6?

Im pretty new to low level, so I'm struggling to understand the Bytes concept.

Comment: how did you get 4*5? characters are 1 byte each

Comment: oh
okay thanks
so is this 6 or does the null terminator has a different amount of bytes

Comment: null terminator is just a zero byte, a char like any other

Comment: What does the documentation of `strcpy` say?

Answer (score 1):

[`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy):

> Copies the null-terminated byte string pointed to by `src`, including the null terminator, to the character array whose first element is pointed to by `dest`.

Answer (score 0):

`"hello"` is a *string* of 6 characters as in C, a *string* includes the null character.

> "string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character." C17 § 7.1.1.1

All 6 are copied with `strcpy()`.